# Can't install gphoto2 on Yocto Linux

Tags: linux, libraries, yocto

I recently discovered how to connect to a PTP-compatible camera from Linux so I figured I could do the same from a Galileo Gen 2 board, only to find out that it's not as easy as I thought. The Yocto Linux image I'm using is **iot-devkit-201510010757-mmcblkp0-galileo**

The first riddle was installing libgphoto2. I started by downloading a copy of libgphoto 2.5.4 on my Galileo(actually used WinSCP to transfer it) and tried to run ./configure, only to find out that I have a missing dependency, namely libtool-ltld. The specific error message was:

*libgphoto2 requires libltdl (the libtool dl* library)*

Ok, searching for that I discovered the [GNU libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/) site and proceeded to try to install that. For whatever reasons I've completely forgot( it's been 6 hours of searching for a solution now), I couldn't install it( I think *make* and *make install* might have worked but libgphoto still complained about not having libtool-ltld?). So I went another route for installing this.

On whatever site/forum somebody suggested the usage of another repository for the *opkg* package manager, namely [AlexT's repo](http://alextgalileo.altervista.org/package-repo-configuration-instructions.html) for Galileo. Good, I've put in base-feeds.conf the links provided there and tried to run **opkg update** only to get a "wget: bad address" error(holy crap dude, I'm just trying to install a library!). Turns out I manually had to put the 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 Google DNS servers in resolv.conf.

**opkg list** looks like a total mess now, but at least I can finally install libgphoto2-2. Of course, I have to **-force-overwrite install** it because there are some conflicts but I don't care at this point. Turns out the installed version is 2.4.11.

gphoto2 isn't on the repo unfortunately, so I download again the gphoto2 2.4.11 version and try to run ./configure.
The result?

> configure: error: PKG_CONFIG_PATH= LIBGPHOTO2_LIBS= LIBGPHOTO2_CFLAGS=
>
> - Fatal: gphoto2 command line interface requires libgphoto2 >= 2.5.6 to build.
>     *
> - Possible solutions:
> - - set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to adequate value
> - - call configure with LIBGPHOTO2_LIBS=.. and LIBGPHOTO2_CFLAGS=..
> - - call configure with one of the --with-libgphoto2 parameters
> - - get libgphoto2 and install it

When typing **export** there is not PKG_CONFIG_PATH to be found and I really wasted all of my known options on how to resolve this. *libgphoto2* seems to be installed, at least I found these files in /usr/lib :

- libgphoto2.so.2
- libgphoto2.so.2.4.0
- libgphoto2_port.so.0
- libgphoto2_port.so.0.8.0

What am I doing wrong?